# Just run program on NXT, not download?

Tags: nxt, usb

Is there any way I can simply run a program on the NXT, but not download it?
  I have all my programs already downloaded, and I am connecting with a USB cable to a MacBook Pro using the NXT-G interface.  Is there any way I can just run programs existing on the NXT from the computer, and not download them?  It's really increasing my robot's run time.


  I am competing in Robocross in Science Olympiad, and my event is at noon.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There have been some projects that allow you to run NXT programs on a computer, like this one:
http://ocaml-mindstorm.forge.ocamlcore.org/

However, this is done by downloading and running a different program on the NXT, which acts as a communications bridge -- passing control to and from the main computer.  There are probably other libraries that use this model of operation, so you might not need to learn OCaml specifically to try this.

Downloading programs onto the NXT is the only way that they can be run; there is no concept of a filesystem or external memory device on a microcontroller that you could use as an alternate source of the program instructions.

Comment: After much deliberation, I have decided to use LeJOS, which has an external program for running programs on the NXT filesystem that it installs with its firmware.  Thank you for your answer, though.